# "Funnily enough" vs. "amazingly enough"

Tags: word-difference

According to [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/funnily-enough), **funnily enough** means:

> You use funnily enough to indicate that, although something is
>   surprising, it is true or really happened.

That basically sounds to me like a definition of **amazingly enough** as well. Is there a major difference or can they be used more or less interchangeably?

Comment: Even though I know that **funny** can mean "strange," I still associate it with "humorous." So, when I hear the phrase **funnily enough** part of me always thinks of it that way. Sometimes something *can* be both humorous and surprising at the same time, but if something is *only* surprising, and not at all humorous, I'll just say **strangely enough**. (I have never used **amazingly enough**, and I can't specifically recall hearing it before either. Although, I have used **amazingly** on its own.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Funnily* is weaker than *amazingly*.

> - Funnily enough, the woman in front of me on the bus was my sister's boss.
> - I lost my job and amazingly enough, I won a million dollars on the lottery the next day.